# Quick Sort using two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to use two threads to handle the first array split in quick sort to speed up the process. My running time is a little bit faster, but usually is the same running time without using threads. What could be the problem? I allow the the quick sort method using two threads to run once in a for loop which then return an array that is passed to the quicksort method that does not use threads.

```
public class Partitioning {
    private static boolean Switch = true;

    public static void quickSort(int[] array) throws InterruptedException{
        quicksort(array, 0, array.length-1);
    }

    private static int pivotG(int[] array, int left, int right){
        int pivot = array[(left+right)/2];
        return pivot;
    }

    private static int indexG(int[] array, int left, int right, int pivot){
        int index = partition(array, left, right, pivot);
        return index;
    }

    private static void quicksort(int[] array, int left, int right) throws InterruptedException {
        if (left>= right){
            return;
        }
        Object lock = new Object();

        if (isSwitch()){
        Thread t1 = new Thread (new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                int pivot = pivotG (array, left, right);
                int index = indexG(array, left, right, pivot);
                try {
                    quicksort(array, left, index-1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Thread t2 = new Thread (new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                int pivot = pivotG (array, left, right);
                int index = indexG(array, left, right, pivot);
                try {
                    quicksort(array, index, right);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        setSwitch (false);

        }else{
            int pivot = pivotG (array, left, right);
            int index = indexG(array, left, right, pivot);
            quicksort(array, left, index-1);
            quicksort(array, index, right);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[] array, int left, int right, int pivot) {
        while (left<=right){
            while (array[left]< pivot){
                left++;
            }
            while (array[right]>pivot){
                right--;
            }
            if (left<=right){
                int temp1 = array[left];
                int temp2 = array[right];
                array[left] = temp2;
                array[right] = temp1;
                left++;
                right--;
            }
        }
        return left; 
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws InterruptedException{
        long time1 = System.nanoTime();
        Random ra =new Random();
        int[] list1 = new int[1000];
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
            list1[i] = ra.nextInt(1000);
        }
        quickSort(list1);

        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - time1;
        long finalSec = (elapsed/1000000 );
        System.out.println("time it took           "+finalSec);
    }

    public static boolean isSwitch() {
        return Switch;
    }

    public static void setSwitch(boolean switch1) {
        Switch = switch1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many cores do you have?

Comment: my processor is a 2.3GHz dual-core Intel Core i5. but i think there is something wrong with the code because I dont fully understand how to implements the use of threads into my quicksort algorithm .

Comment: `IntStream.of(array).parallel().sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);` - but it's probably slower than `IntStream.of(array).sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);` - there is overhead to thread coordination.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it actually sorts correctly because you don't wait on the result of the threads.

Comment: should the threads return something? and how do I wait for the results of thread?

Comment: I would be surprised if the time to set up two sort threads on different cores was faster than sorting a 1000-element array on 1 core.  Might be significant if you had 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing doing 1000000 printlns is going to have a serious effect on performance. Get your end time first. For another, I don't think you've implemented quick sort correctly. You should confirm with smaller datasets